# No content to map to Object due to end of input when getting InputStream from ContainerRequestContext

Tags: java, rest, filter, jax-rs

When I am getting `InputStream` from `ContainerRequestContext` in code facing following exception

> Caused by: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input"

The Request:

```
{
    "header": {
    "userId": "TEST",
    "mode": "NONE"
    },
    "entityList": [
        {
            "id": 424260,
            "status": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

The java code is:

```html
@Provider
public class RestHeaderFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(RestHeaderFilter.class);

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = request.getEntityStream();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to validate header information, i am calling service in following way

```html
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/submitUser")
    public ResponseOb submitUser(UserDtl req) {
        ResponseOb resp = new ResponseOb();
        return resp;
    }
```

Comment: how are you invoking your webservice? What is the HTTP method you a re using? Could you post all these details also as it is not clear from your current code.

Comment: @YugSingh - thanks, i have added info

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496917/2587435